# Preselect item in an MVC3 Html.DropDownlListFor() that is bound to an ENUM list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, selectlist, html.dropdownlistfor

I am binding an MVC (3) selectList to an enum using the following helper method

```
public static List<SelectListItem> GetSelectList<T>()
{
    Type enumType = typeof(T);
    if (!enumType.IsEnum)
        throw new ArgumentException("The specified type is not enum");

    List<SelectListItem> enumList = new List<SelectListItem>();

    var values = Enum.GetValues(enumType);

    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        SelectListItem newItem = new SelectListItem();

        newItem.Value = Convert.ToInt32(value).ToString();
        newItem.Text = Regex.Replace(Enum.GetName(enumType, value), "([a-z](?=[A-Z])|[A-Z](?=[A-Z][a-z]))", "$1 ");

        enumList.Add(newItem);
    }
    return enumList;
}
```

Then calling the method in my controller and passing the fourth parameter to the selectList constructor as the preselected id of the customer type.

```
 _view.CustomerTypeSelectList = new SelectList(EnumHelper.GetSelectList<CustomerTypeEnum>(), "Value", "Text", _customer.TypeID);
```

Then in the view I bind the selectList

```
<%=Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CustomerTypeId, Model.CustomerTypeSelectList )%>
```

However I cannot get the selectList to pre-populate.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is method `GetSelectList` returning the list of select list items?

Comment: Yes it returns a set of selectList items fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You fill the enumList  with string-string value pairs so when specifying the selected element you should use string as well (with Convert.ToInt32 and ToString).
In your GetSelectList helper you should return SelectList like this:

```
_view.CustomerTypeSelectList = new SelectList(EnumHelper.GetSelectList<CustomerTypeEnum>(), "Value", "Text", Convert.ToInt32(_customer.TypeID).ToString());
```

Better solution would be to use enum values for value column and return SelectList object from GetSelectList:

```
    public static SelectList GetSelectList<T>()
    {
        Type enumType = typeof(T);
            if (!enumType.IsEnum)
                throw new ArgumentException("The specified type is not enum");

        var values = Enum.GetValues(enumType);
        var enumList = values.Select(e=>new { Value = e , Text = Regex.Replace(Enum.GetName(enumType, e), "([a-z](?=[A-Z])|[A-Z](?=[A-Z][a-z]))", "$1 ") })
        var selectList = new SelectList(values, "Value", "Text", enumObj);
        return selectList;
}
```

Comment: Thanks yes it does now preselect the item in the selectList however if I select another item in the list the 

    x => x.CustomerTypeId

is always zero

Comment: Probably CustomerTypeId property of your Model should be of type string in order do be properly handled by Html.DropDownListFor helper. Another solution would be to use Enum values instead of strings.